# GsonBuilder toJSon() is not encoding non-english characterset properly

Tags: java, windows, encoding, utf-8, gson

The characters in the content are received like below by server. When I run the same code on Mac OSX then it goes as expected, but when the same program is run on a windows machine, I am getting this behavior, there is no issue with server code because when I call this API from Postman and pass this characters then they are received correctly by the server. It seems GsonBuilder has some issue in processing non-English characters. I face this issue with few other languages as well.

> Εισιτή�?ια

```
        private String content =  "Εισιτήρια";

        public String post(String targetEnvironment) throws IOException{

        String gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(java.lang.reflect.Modifier.TRANSIENT).setLenient().create().toJson(this).toString();
            System.out.println(gson);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, gson);
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
              .url(targetEnvironment)
              .post(body)
              .addHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
              .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
              .addHeader("client_application_id", "1")
              .addHeader("x-requested-with", "1")
              .addHeader("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5)")
              .addHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip,deflate,br")
              .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
              .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            String response_string = response.body().string();
            System.out.println(response_string);
         }
```

Comment: You say that it works on Mac but also suspect that the code has some issue. Do you mean to say that the code is not platform independent?

Comment: I did not mention that my code has an issue, I am saying Gson library code may not be handling character encoding properly on different platforms. I am not really sure, is there a way to set a character encoding option to GsonBuilder while calling toJson()

Comment: Do you know the file encoding that your jvm is using on Windows and on OSX? It's possible that the default being used on each is different. Within your invocation of `RequestBody.create` you should make explicit the type of encoding you are using. Ex: call `RequestBody.create(JSON,  gson.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: I am really not sure what file encoding being used by jvm in each of these platforms, my windows machine is Windows Server 2008 R2,  I will try using the above code and check if it can fix it.

Comment: Try and see what happens if you print `content` instead of  `response_string`.

Comment: I am printing it right after the toJson() call and it is printing it as ??????????. I have tried @RickRidley suggestion, but it is now going as ??????????  to the server.

Comment: @RickRidley the encoding messed up right after calling the toJson() of GsonBuilder, so setting it in the RequestBody as suggested by is not helping to resolve this issue.